# Interpolating values in UTM grid

Tags: qgis, r, interpolation, utm, spain

I've got a 10x10 km UTM grid (vector file), which I want to use for showing the distribution and abundance of a bird species. For each cell, I've got a value for the survey effort (number of days, ranging from 0 to 2,000) and the number of birds recorded (from 0 to 600).

The grid consists of 5,600 cells, of which around 2,500 have been surveyed (in blue) to a greater or lesser extent. Of these, cells with the highest bird counts are in the eastern coast and in the islands.

[image]

How can I produce a map for the whole area, interpolating ponderated values (like number of birds per 100 visits) in non surveyed cells using QGIS?

Comment: What's the size of your grid, and how many unsurveyed cells have you got? Does a map of the surveyed cells show any smoothness or pattern? What do you want to interpolate - presence/absence of birds or something like number of birds per 100 visits?

Comment: By asking how to do the same thing in either of two products you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad for focused Q&A.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.

Comment: Given the large contiguous areas of unsurveyed cells, filling these through interpolation (or any other method) is unlikely to produce anything of meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Look into USGS PRESENCE software
https://www.mbr-pwrc.usgs.gov/software/presence.html

Comment: Unable to install the R package in Mac :-(

Comment: there is a package for OSX/Linux on that page under downloads

Comment: Yeah, there is, and I've tried to install the tar.gz file without any success :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

- polygon centroid tool on your grid
- TIN interpolation on your result from the polygon centroid tool
- Raster zonal statistics using the result of the tin interpolation and your original grid for the zones
- your grid should have a column added to its table with “_mean” (or another valuetype if you have chosen such)

Edit:

I can interpolate on the prim-ponde value.
[image]

The larger you set your pixel size, the less CPU strain.

Comment: Working on this, but experiencing difficulties with the very first step in QGIS.

Comment: @JesúsPinilla I’ve altered the steps in the answer. Maybe that will work better. Do you have sample data to work with?

Comment: I'd already made the centroid step, but sth doesn't work with the TIN interpolation and I'm unable to work it out. Sample points in https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbwrwrxyibdgpq0/sample.zip?dl=0

Comment: Before you do the centroid step: select by value on the gridfile: select all features where the value > 0. The do the centroid step with only the selected features

Comment: already done: select all, select >= 0, select > 0. TIN interpolation (in QGIS 3.10) doesn't run

Comment: You're right, CPU issues! Still working on it.